How to compile iOS Cocoapods dependency using Scons?
I am trying to create an iOS plugin for Godot Game Engine. Now my plugin requires integration with FirebaseAuth so I created a Podfile and added those dependencies. Here is the complete source code
This is my SConstruct file
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import subprocess

if sys.version_info < (3,):
    def decode_utf8(x):
        return x
else:
    import codecs
    def decode_utf8(x):
        return codecs.utf_8_decode(x)[0]

# Most of the settings are taken from https://github.com/BastiaanOlij/gdnative_cpp_example

opts = Variables([], ARGUMENTS)

# Gets the standard flags CC, CCX, etc.
env = DefaultEnvironment()

# Define our options
opts.Add(EnumVariable('target', "Compilation target", 'debug', ['debug', 'release', "release_debug"]))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('arch', "Compilation Architecture", '', ['', 'arm64', 'armv7', 'x86_64']))
opts.Add(BoolVariable('simulator', "Compilation platform", 'no'))
opts.Add(BoolVariable('use_llvm', "Use the LLVM / Clang compiler", 'no'))
opts.Add(PathVariable('target_path', 'The path where the lib is installed.', 'bin/'))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('plugin', 'Plugin to build', '', ['', 'arithematic']))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('version', 'Godot version to target', '', ['', '3.x', '4.0']))

# Updates the environment with the option variables.
opts.Update(env)

# Process some arguments
if env['use_llvm']:
    env['CC'] = 'clang'
    env['CXX'] = 'clang++'

if env['arch'] == '':
    print("No valid arch selected.")
    quit();

if env['plugin'] == '':
    print("No valid plugin selected.")
    quit();

if env['version'] == '':
    print("No valid Godot version selected.")
    quit();

# For the reference:
# - CCFLAGS are compilation flags shared between C and C++
# - CFLAGS are for C-specific compilation flags
# - CXXFLAGS are for C++-specific compilation flags
# - CPPFLAGS are for pre-processor flags
# - CPPDEFINES are for pre-processor defines
# - LINKFLAGS are for linking flags

# Enable Obj-C modules
env.Append(CCFLAGS=["-fmodules", "-fcxx-modules"])

if env['simulator']:
    sdk_name = 'iphonesimulator'
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-mios-simulator-version-min=10.0'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=["-mios-simulator-version-min=10.0"])
else:
    sdk_name = 'iphoneos'
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-miphoneos-version-min=10.0'])
    env.Append(LINKFLAGS=["-miphoneos-version-min=10.0"])

try:
    sdk_path = decode_utf8(subprocess.check_output(['xcrun', '--sdk', sdk_name, '--show-sdk-path']).strip())
except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, OSError):
    raise ValueError("Failed to find SDK path while running xcrun --sdk {} --show-sdk-path.".format(sdk_name))

env.Append(CCFLAGS=[
    '-fobjc-arc', 
    '-fmessage-length=0', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info', 
    '-fdiagnostics-show-category=id', '-fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits', '-fpascal-strings', 
    '-fblocks', '-fvisibility=hidden', '-MMD', '-MT', 'dependencies', '-fno-exceptions', 
    '-Wno-ambiguous-macro', 
    '-Wall', '-Werror=return-type',
    # '-Wextra',
])

env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-arch', env['arch'], "-isysroot", "$IOS_SDK_PATH", "-stdlib=libc++", '-isysroot', sdk_path])
env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-DPTRCALL_ENABLED'])
env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
    '-DNEED_LONG_INT', '-DLIBYUV_DISABLE_NEON', 
    '-DIOS_ENABLED', '-DUNIX_ENABLED', '-DCOREAUDIO_ENABLED'
])
env.Append(LINKFLAGS=["-arch", env['arch'], '-isysroot', sdk_path, '-F' + sdk_path])

if env['arch'] == 'armv7':
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fno-aligned-allocation'])

if env['version'] == '3.x':
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=["$IPHONESDK"])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DIPHONE_ENABLED'])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DVERSION_3_X'])

    env.Prepend(CFLAGS=['-std=gnu11'])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DGLES_ENABLED', '-std=gnu++14'])

    if env['target'] == 'debug':
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-gdwarf-2', '-O0', 
            '-DDEBUG_MEMORY_ALLOC', '-DDISABLE_FORCED_INLINE', 
            '-D_DEBUG', '-DDEBUG=1', '-DDEBUG_ENABLED',
            '-DPTRCALL_ENABLED',
        ])
    elif env['target'] == 'release_debug':
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-O2', '-ftree-vectorize',
            '-DNDEBUG', '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1', '-DDEBUG_ENABLED', 
            '-DPTRCALL_ENABLED',
        ])

        if env['arch'] != 'armv7':
            env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fomit-frame-pointer'])
    else:
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-O2', '-ftree-vectorize',
            '-DNDEBUG', '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1', 
            '-DPTRCALL_ENABLED',
        ])

        if env['arch'] != 'armv7':
            env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fomit-frame-pointer'])
elif env['version'] == '4.0':
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=["$IOS_SDK_PATH"])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DIOS_ENABLED'])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DVERSION_4_0'])

    env.Prepend(CFLAGS=['-std=gnu11'])
    env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-DVULKAN_ENABLED', '-std=gnu++17'])

    if env['target'] == 'debug':
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-gdwarf-2', '-O0', 
            '-DDEBUG_MEMORY_ALLOC', '-DDISABLE_FORCED_INLINE', 
            '-D_DEBUG', '-DDEBUG=1', '-DDEBUG_ENABLED', 
        ])
    elif env['target'] == 'release_debug':
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-O2', '-ftree-vectorize',
            '-DNDEBUG', '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1', '-DDEBUG_ENABLED',
        ])

        if env['arch'] != 'armv7':
            env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fomit-frame-pointer'])
    else:
        env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=[
            '-O2', '-ftree-vectorize',
            '-DNDEBUG', '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1',
        ])

        if env['arch'] != 'armv7':
            env.Prepend(CXXFLAGS=['-fomit-frame-pointer'])            
else:
    print("No valid version to set flags for.")
    quit();

# Adding header files
if env['version'] == '3.x':
    env.Append(CPPPATH=[
        '.', 
        'godot', 
        'godot/platform/iphone',
    ])
else:
       env.Append(CPPPATH=[
        '.', 
        'godot', 
        'godot/platform/ios',
    ])
       


sources = Glob('arithematic/*.cpp')

sources.append(Glob('arithematic/*.mm'))
sources.append(Glob('arithematic/*.m'))


library_platform = env["arch"] + "-" + ("simulator" if env["simulator"] else "iphone")
library_name = env['plugin'] + "." + library_platform + "." + env["target"] + ".a"
library = env.StaticLibrary(target=env['target_path'] + library_name, source=sources)

If I run scons target=release_debug arch=arm64 plugin=arithematic version=4.0 I get error saying
In file included from arithematic/arithematic.mm:16:
arithematic/arithematic.h:19:9:{19:9-19:38}: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found [1]
 #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
scons: *** [arithematic/arithematic.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
    
    Default(library)
    
    # Generates help for the -h scons option.
    Help(opts.GenerateHelpText(env))

then I added
sources.append(Glob('Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/*.m'))
sources.append(Glob('Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/*.m'))

and ran the command again but now I get
Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.m:17:9:{17:9-17:59}: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h' file not found [1]
 #import "FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
scons: *** [Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.

Is there a way to include the entire Pods folder as there are multiple sub directories within directories
Also I tried
def collect_sources(directory, extensions):
    sources = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(extensions):
                sources.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return sources

pod_sources = collect_sources('Pods', ('.m', '.mm', '.cpp', '.h'))
sources.extend(pod_sources)

but it gives error saying
Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.m:17:9:{17:9-17:59}: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h' file not found [1]
 #import "FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
scons: *** [Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.

EDIT:
Compile CommandLine:
Command:  gcc -o Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.o -c -std=gnu11 -fmodules -fcxx-modules -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -fobjc-arc -fmessage-length=0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -fpascal-strings -fblocks -fvisibility=hidden -MMD -MT dependencies -fno-exceptions -Wno-ambiguous-macro -Wall -Werror=return-type -arch arm64 -isysroot -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.5.sdk -DPTRCALL_ENABLED -I. -Igodot -Igodot/platform/ios Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.m
Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.m:17:9:{17:9-17:59}: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h' file not found [1]

EDIT 2:
Include FirebaseCore in include paths
So I added below code to SConstruct
def find_include_dirs(root_dir):
    include_dirs = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_dir):
        if any(filename.endswith('.h') for filename in filenames):
            include_dirs.append(dirpath)
    return include_dirs

include_dirs = find_include_dirs('Pods')
env.Append(CPPPATH=include_dirs)

Here is the command line
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.o -c -std=gnu11 -fmodules -fcxx-modules -miphoneos-version-min=16.0 -fobjc-arc -fmessage-length=0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -fpascal-strings -fblocks -fvisibility=hidden -MMD -MT dependencies -fno-exceptions -Wno-ambiguous-macro -Wall -Werror=return-type -arch arm64 -isysroot -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.5.sdk -DPTRCALL_ENABLED -I. -Igodot -Igodot/platform/ios -IPods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Extension -IPods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources -IPods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/Public/FirebaseCore -IPods/RecaptchaInterop/RecaptchaEnterprise/RecaptchaInterop/Public/RecaptchaInterop -IPods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include "-IPods/Target Support Files/FirebaseCore" "-IPods/Target Support Files/RecaptchaInterop" "-IPods/Target Support Files/PromisesObjC" "-IPods/Target Support Files/FirebaseAuth" "-IPods/Target Support Files/FirebaseAppCheckInterop" "-IPods/Target Support Files/GTMSessionFetcher" "-IPods/Target Support Files/FirebaseCoreInternal" "-IPods/Target Support Files/Pods-arithematic" "-IPods/Target Support Files/GoogleUtilities" -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseCore/Extension -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Interop -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Auth -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/SystemService -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/MultiFactor -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/MultiFactor/Phone -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/MultiFactor/TOTP -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/User -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Backend -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Backend/RPC -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Backend/RPC/Proto -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Backend/RPC/Proto/Phone -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Backend/RPC/Proto/TOTP -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Backend/RPC/MultiFactor/Enroll -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Backend/RPC/MultiFactor/SignIn -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Backend/RPC/MultiFactor/Unenroll -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Storage -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Utilities -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Public/FirebaseAuth -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/GameCenter -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/Twitter -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/OAuth -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/Google -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/GitHub -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/Facebook -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/Phone -IPods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/Email -IPods/FirebaseAppCheckInterop/FirebaseAppCheck/Interop/Public/FirebaseAppCheckInterop -IPods/GTMSessionFetcher/Sources/Core -IPods/GTMSessionFetcher/Sources/Core/Public/GTMSessionFetcher -IPods/GoogleUtilities/third_party/IsAppEncrypted/Public -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Logger/Public/GoogleUtilities -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Network -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Network/Public/GoogleUtilities -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Common -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Reachability -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Reachability/Public/GoogleUtilities -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Internal -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler/Public/GoogleUtilities -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Environment/Public/GoogleUtilities -IPods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib/Public/GoogleUtilities Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.m
Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.m:17:9:{17:9-17:59}: fatal error: 'FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h' file not found [1]
 #import "FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
scons: *** [Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.


Can you share the compile command line? At first glance looks like you're just missing a single -I<PATH TO FIREBASE> ..

@bdbaddog scons target=release_debug arch=arm64 plugin=arithematic version=4.0 include_dir=Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/Public,Pods/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth/Sources/Public

That's not the compiler command line, that's your SCons command line. I was asking for the compiler command line. You may have to enable verbose output.. Not sure how godot's got it set up..

@bdbaddog I have edited my question to add the compiler command line, couldn't add it in the comments as it was too long. can you please check

You need to add the path to FireBase core in your include path.. it's not showing on the compiler command line

@bdbaddog I updated my question to add FireBase core in your include path but still facing similar issue. Let me know what else I am missing

Looks like you want to compile FirebaseCore/FirebaseAuth from the sources pulled by Cocoapods. Cocoapods is meant to be integrated by Xcode, and if you want to compile your static library from the source codes of Firebase, It's possible, but I guess we should learn the podspec of Firebase. It is just too complicated.
It is better to link against the compiled xcframeworks from Firebase:

Then I downloaded the compiled xcframeworks, removed the cocoapods, the xcworkspace project and other unnecessary files. Made some changes to your Sconstruct file:
if env['simulator']:
    env.Append(LIBPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAuth.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator'])
    env.Append(CPPPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAuth.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/FirebaseAuth.framework/Headers'])
    env.Append(LIBPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseCore.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/FirebaseCore.framework'])
    env.Append(CPPPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseCore.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/FirebaseCore.framework/Headers'])
else:
    env.Append(LIBPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAuth.xcframework/ios-arm64'])
    env.Append(CPPPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAuth.xcframework/ios-arm64/FirebaseAuth.framework/Headers'])
    env.Append(LIBPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseCore.xcframework/ios-arm64/FirebaseCore.framework'])
    env.Append(CPPPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseCore.xcframework/ios-arm64/FirebaseCore.framework/Headers'])


You will also need to change angled imports to quoted include:
// #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
// #import <FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.h>

#include "FirebaseCore.h"
#include "FirebaseAuth.h"

After these modifications you can compile the project.
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o arithematic/arithematic.o -c -fomit-frame-pointer -O2 -ftree-vectorize -DNDEBUG -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DDEBUG_ENABLED -DVULKAN_ENABLED -std=gnu++17 -DVERSION_4_0 -DIOS_ENABLED -DNEED_LONG_INT -DLIBYUV_DISABLE_NEON -DIOS_ENABLED -DUNIX_ENABLED -DCOREAUDIO_ENABLED -fmodules -fcxx-modules -miphoneos-version-min=10.0 -fobjc-arc -fmessage-length=0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -fpascal-strings -fblocks -fvisibility=hidden -MMD -MT dependencies -fno-exceptions -Wno-ambiguous-macro -Wall -Werror=return-type -arch arm64 -isysroot -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.5.sdk -DPTRCALL_ENABLED -I. -Igodot -Igodot/platform/ios -IFirebase/FirebaseAuth.xcframework/ios-arm64/FirebaseAuth.framework/Headers -IFirebase/FirebaseCore.xcframework/ios-arm64/FirebaseCore.framework/Headers arithematic/arithematic.mm
scons: `bin/libarithematic.arm64-iphone.release_debug.a' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.

BTW, above workaround is in this github Repo

The issue is still there. Firstly the error you're getting is because I removed the Godot folder from source code as it was too big for Github. Check here for full source code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YDaOkv2tMw2W89sSC6DiS_zcsaFz1k9g/view?usp=sharing where I tried your approach. Also I think the firebase paths you added are incorrect. Also sources.append(Glob('Pods/..... is not needed after removing Pods

let me have a look.

it's updated, please pull the code.

I don't see FirebaseCore inside Firebase folder so now I get issue saying #include "FirebaseCore.h"

Update your answer with this
 env.Append(LIBPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.xcframework/ios-arm64'])     env.Append(CPPPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.xcframework/ios-arm64/FirebaseAuth.framework/Headers'])     env.Append(LIBPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseCore.xcframework/ios-arm64/FirebaseCore.framework'])     env.Append(CPPPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseCore.xcframework/ios-arm64/FirebaseCore.framework/Headers'])

pull again, some project files are ignored by gitignore file. now it should compiles.

do you have any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78575276/godot-ios-export-leads-to-arm64-linker-error-for-firebase

i'll take a look, no worry

I think it's hard to help without more details, evilisnj@gmail.com is my mail address.

Can you let me know what more details you expect. Once the '.a' file is generated for my iOS plugin , I just copy pasted it to the ios/plugins folder of my Godot Game and changes its name to my iOS static library plugin name and just after exporting the project from Godot Game engine , I get the error

The actual Xcode project structure. In our compiled static library file, the symbols of filebase are not included, therefore we need to link against firebase libraries as well

Thanks what do you mean by symbols of firebase? Is there a separate file which I need to include in scons just like we have the added the headers and libraries in scons

firebasecore.xcframework and firbaseauth.xcframework

same issue even after adding env.Append(LIBPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.xcframework']) & env.Append(LIBPATH=['Firebase/FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseCore.xcframework) , I have also linked them in  Link Binary with Libraries in Xcode while creating the plugin
